# Stripe - expand Product data with Prices

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Basically I'm just trying to expand the product call in stripe with prices, so I don't have to make another API for each product that's retrieved.

```
Product.list(ProductListParams.builder()
                    .setActive(true)
                    .addExpand("data.prices")
                    .build());
```

I've tried both data.prices and data.price but the Product Collection response -> defaultPrice is still just returning the prices id with a null expandable object.

I've also tried data.defaultPrice, but the call fails completely in this case.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't list all of a product's prices from the list products call. To get a full list of prices by product, you will need to make a List Prices call for each product ID that you want the prices for.[1]

The reason that you are getting an error is that Stripe's Product objects do not have a `prices` field to expand. This call will work if you specify an expandable field that products do have such as `default_price`.

[1] https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list#list_prices-product

[2] https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/products/object

Comment: Thanks Pompey, I should have been using default_price. It's a subscription based product so only needs to return one price for each project and seems to be eagerly loading it now.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the accepted answer unfortunately you can't list all of a product's prices from the list products call.

However, you can use the [search api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/search) of stripe and get the data. This would require you to make two calls one to fetch your products and the other to fetch prices for all the retrieved products.

Sample calls:

Fetch the products:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/products/search \
  -u sk_test_xxxxx: \
  --data-urlencode query="active:'true'" \
  -G
```

Fetch the prices of the retrieved products:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices/search \
  -u sk_test_xxxxx: \
  --data-urlencode query="product:'prod_xxxx' OR product:'prod_yyy'" \
  -G
```